# How to multiple all map values by a factor in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

For example if the map is equal to:

```
z = ['x':1, 'y':2]
```

For f(2) I would like it to become:

```
[x':2, 'y':4]
```

I know it could be done using a .each loop, question is whether there is a simpler way.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the [`collectEntries`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) function, which is applied to all keys and values in a `Map`, and returns a **new** `Map` with the updated values:

```
def z = [x:1, y:2]
z = z.collectEntries{ key, value -> [(key): value*2] }
assert z == [x:2, y:4]
```

A couple of notes here:

- First, you don't need to quote string keys in map literals, meaning `['z':1]` is the same as `[z:1]`, but the latter is groovier and more legible
- Second, the return value of the `collectEntries` closure must be a map, so be careful there
- Third, when providing dynamic keys in a map, you need to wrap them in parentheses, so you need to use `(key)`, not just `key`
- Fourth, you need to assign the result of the method, it doesn't act in-place.

---

However, it's almost certainly just be cleaner to use `each()` with the single-argument closure, like so:

```
def z = [x:1, y:2]
z.each{ it.value = it.value*2 }
assert z == [x:2, y:4]
```

There's less gotchyas this way, and it modifies the map in-place, so you don't have to reassign the variable.

Comment: +1. One small note: the closure passed to `collectEntries` can also return a two-element list containing the key and value of the new entry, so the example closure could also be `{ k, v -> [k, v * 2]}` (which does not require the parens-around-the-key "trick").

Comment: I thought it could, but didn't catch it in the docs.  It's there, of course!  Thanks!